# How can I customize the size of calendar in flutter table_calendar?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, calendar

Can I make this calendar bigger enough to fill whole screen?

I searched some parameter like size, but I couldn't find it.
Also, I searched whether there is any padding in day cell that I can customize, but I couldn't find it, too.

If you know the way to change its size, or other widget that can change the size, pls teach me some.
Thank you, and sorry for my bad English.
(I'm not an English user)

[here is the image of default size of calendar !click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F66Y9.png)

Comment: my Dear ! can you please show us the calendar :)

Comment: Yes, I edited! You can see the image in link below

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i don't sure my answer is the best solution or not ... but some time's this is the only way ...
you can find your packages file (from github) and copy them in your project root folder and in `pubspec.yaml` file
address it like this.

```
dependencies:
  plugin1:
   path: ./plugin1/
```

and after this local addressing you can change every thing like other yours code.

Comment: Um actually I don't use github.. :( but thank your for your advice!